# Force install location in Badge installation of AIR applications

Tags: air

Is there a way to force install location when installing an AIR application via badge install? We don't want the user's to modify the installation location of the application.

Regards,
Sandeep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learned the hard way - there is not way to do that! :(